# Mysql syntax error when refreshing a dataset

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-gateway

This error occurs on the Power BI web app. It says I can't connect to an undefined dataset and it says I have a SQL syntax error.

I get this error everytime I try to refresh the dataset
[image: error]

The thing is, there is not syntax error on the query. The query run successfully on the MySQL console. The query with the error even changes if I try to refresh the data one more time.

This process was working fine until I choose a on-premises gateway to enable data auto-refresh and mapped to the report.
[image: gateway-config]

Now, every time i try to refresh the dataset I get a sql syntax error in a different query. Anyone knows what might be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the Power Query look like?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: the Power Query is correct David, I can refresh no problems and without SQL errors